# Typing function which merges objects typescript

Tags: typescript, object

So, basically I have 2 interfaces, one extends another. I want to create a function which will merge incoming object with default value and return merged object properly typed. How can I achieve this with TypeScript?

```js
interface MyBaseInterface {
  foo: boolean;
  bar?: () => void;
}
interface MyInterface extends MyBaseInterface {
  baz?: any;
}

const defaultValue = {
  foo: false,
};
```

```js
//my pretty bad solution
const merge = <T extends MyBaseInterface & MyInterface>(val?: T): T => {
  return (val ? { ...defaultValue, ...val } : defaultValue) as any;
};


const function1 = (opt?: MyBaseInterface) => {
  //merged options should be typed as MyBaseInterface
  const mergedOptions = merge(opt);
  //process with options
  return 'something';
};

const function2 = (opt?: MyInterface) => {
  //merged options should be typed as MyInterface
  const mergedOptions = merge(opt);
  //process with options
  return 'something';
};

//but that solution allows something like this 
//and mostly i understand why, but anyways is there is better solution?

const function3 = (opt?: MyInterface) => {
  //no warns about something
  const mergedOptions = merge({ ...opt, something: 'something' }); 
  //process with options
  return 'something';
};
```

```js
//one more solution is to just assert type 

const mergedOptions = merge(opt) as MyInterface;
const mergedOptions = merge(opt) as MyBaseInterface;

//and merge function becomes something like this
const merge = (val?: MyInterface | MyBaseInterface) => {
  return val ? { ...defaultValue, ...val } : defaultValue;
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to express? `{ ...opt, something: 'something' }` is of type `MyInterface & { something: 'something' }`, which does actually extend `MyInterface`, hence is a valid input to the function. If you want to avoid allowing unknown fields, then drop the `extends` and just take a `MyInterface` directly.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! But i want merge function to take args of type MyInterface or MyBaseInterface, your suggestion is to type function param as  MyInterface as it is a just a bigger interface? But then i need a function output type to be of type either MyInterface if object of that type was passed or MyBaseInterface

Comment: If it's limited to those two types and nothing else, then you might try using a pair of [overload signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to get what you want.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo big thanks!